# N Level Navigation Menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

Hi i have been working on a online shopping project for gifts .

My Navigation menu has 3 Levels as follows:

> Parent Menu ==> Child Menu ==> Child Sub Menu .

[image]

i have to get all these values from the database table in a hierarchy, i was thinking to design the database table in such a way that request time for fetching menu data from table is minimal.

my idea is to design a table name `navigation_menu` with following parameters :

```
id(as menu id)
Menu_Name
Parent_id
```

```
id(Parent Menu id)   Menu_Name  Parent_id 
 0                   BIRTHDAY      -
 1                   OCASSIONS     -
 2                   GIFTS         -
 3                   SPECIAL       -
 4                   CAKES         0
 5                   OFFERS        1
 6                   GIFTS         0
 7                   SPECIAL CAKE  4
 8                   PHOTO CAKE    4
```

here i can also use stored procedure to check the parent and child relationship,but i don't have any idea to use the output to build navigation menu.
Or can i design the database in a better way to fetch the data more faster (Suggestions required).

Comment: The way that your question is currently worded will most likely result in its closure. Put some effort into building out the navigation menu. If you truly have zero idea how to do that, then you'll need to look for some tutorials.

Comment: Are you trying to build a way of generating websites so a user can define their own menus? Otherwise I can't see the advantage of storing your menu names / structure into the database.

Comment: I'd suggest you either use hierarchy ids or better still a data format that supports hierarchical structures such as XML.  It is unlikely you will ever join or report on your menu structure so there is no advantage to using a normalized structure.

Comment: i have a vague idea of implementation and i can follow the simple approach to query table fetch parent node to menu and then again query table for child node to menu, but i want to make it little faster either using stored procedure or single operation approach, because i am trying to generate the custom defined menus for updating categories dynamically.